# Taking the union of sets

Tags: python

I have a list `l` of sets. To take the union of all the sets in `l` I do:

```
union = set()
for x in l:
   union |= x
```

I have a feeling there is a more economical/functional way of writing this. Can I improve upon this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how I would do it (some corrections as per comments):

```
union_set = set()
union_set.update(*l)
```

or

```
union_set = set.union(*l)
```

Comment: It expands the list out into a bunch of parameters passed to a function or method. For instance, it is like doing `union_set.union(l[0], l[1], l[2],...)`

Comment: @Randomblue see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

Comment: Do you mean `update` (mutates) or `union` (returns a new set)?

Comment: @WolframH, yes, you're quite right. `union` returns a new set while `update` will modify the current one. I've updated my answer. Kind of funny that it took so long for someone to point that out properly.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> l = [set([1, 2, 3]), set([3, 4, 5]), set([0, 1])]
>>> set.union(*l)
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: However @JustinPeel's syntax much cleaner

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a functional approach, there's little more traditional than [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
>>> reduce(set.union, [ set([1,2]), set([3,4]), set([5,6]) ])
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

In Python 3.0, `reduce` can be found in [the functools module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html); in 2.6 and 2.7, it exists both in `functools` and (as in older interpreters) built-in.

Answer (score 3):

```
union = reduce(set.union, l)
```

In Python 2.x, `reduce` is a built-in.  In 3.x, it's in the `functools` module.